# Continuous Query Evaluation with Memgraph

Tags: apache-kafka, memgraphdb, memgraph

I am looking for a way to evalute continuous queries with memgraph. My goal is to write an application, that notifies a user as soon as an event occurs (e.g. a specific pattern is found). The notification should be a message in a kafka topic. Something like the [Neo4J-Kafka-Connector](https://neo4j.com/docs/kafka/quickstart-connect/). Currently I found nothing better, than to write a python script that periodically queries the graph. My problem with that is, that I don't want to query the whole graph every time for performance reasons. I could define a timestamp in python and increment it with every query, but this seems very hacky. Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to connect to Memgraph using Neo4j Kafka Connector.

I’ve created docker-compose.yml:

```
---
version: "3"
services:
  memgraph:
    image: "memgraph/memgraph"
    hostname: memgraph
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "7444:7444"
    volumes:
      - mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph
      - mg_log:/var/log/memgraph
      - mg_etc:/etc/memgraph

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.3.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.3.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.6.0-7.3.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    volumes:
      - ./plugins:/tmp/connect-plugins
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.3.0.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/tmp/connect-plugins"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt neo4j/kafka-connect-neo4j:latest
        /etc/confluent/docker/run

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.3.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
      
volumes:
  mg_lib:
  mg_log:
  mg_etc:
```

Created nodes with:

```
CREATE (:TestSource {name: 'john', surname: 'doe', timestamp: localDateTime()});
CREATE (:TestSource {name: 'mary', surname: 'doe', timestamp: localDateTime()});
CREATE (:TestSource {name: 'jack', surname: 'small', timestamp: localDateTime()});
```

Created `source.neo4j.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Neo4jSourceConnectorAVRO",
  "config": {
    "topic": "my-topic",
    "connector.class": "streams.kafka.connect.source.Neo4jSourceConnector",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "neo4j.server.uri": "bolt://memgraph:7687",
    "neo4j.authentication.basic.username": "",
    "neo4j.authentication.basic.password": "",
    "neo4j.streaming.poll.interval.msecs": 5000,
    "neo4j.streaming.property": "timestamp",
    "neo4j.streaming.from": "LAST_COMMITTED",
    "neo4j.enforce.schema": true,
    "neo4j.source.query": "MATCH (ts:TestSource) RETURN ts.name AS name, ts.surname AS surname, ts.timestamp AS timestamp"
  }
}
```

Created `sink.neo4j.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Neo4jSinkConnectorAVRO",
  "config": {
    "topics": "my-topic",
    "connector.class": "streams.kafka.connect.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "errors.retry.timeout": "-1",
    "errors.retry.delay.max.ms": "1000",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": true,
    "errors.log.include.messages": true,
    "neo4j.server.uri": "bolt://memgraph:7687",
    "neo4j.authentication.basic.username": "",
    "neo4j.authentication.basic.password": "",
    "neo4j.topic.cypher.my-topic": "MERGE (p:Person{name: event.name, surname: event.surname}) MERGE (f:Family{name: event.surname}) MERGE (p)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(f)"
  }
}
```

Tested with: `MATCH (node) RETURN node;`

Added new node using `CREATE (:TestSource {name: 'Ann', surname: 'Bolin', timestamp: localDateTime()});`

Does this help you?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the same connector can be used. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You already have Kafka setup, maybe you can consider KSQL PUSH QUERY for example

select * from stream where event=true emit changes;

This will trigger when event becomes true.

Comment: PUSH Queries would be possible. But sadly self joins and multiple join conditions aren't supported, so these kind of queries are not ideal for path search